# Can I reference java.ecore in project.ecore without relative path? but use module references instead?

Tags: java, emf, acceleo, ecore

In our Project we are using Acceleo to generate Java code from our eCore Models.

We have created a file called "java.ecore" which contains java standards that we are using (e.g. java.io.Closeable)

Now if I want to create a Class in the project specific "project.ecore" which implements Closeable, I can reference the "java.ecore" like so:

```
<eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="ProjectClass" eSuperTypes="relative/path/to/java.ecore#//io/Closeable" />
```

The part `relative/path/to/` gives me a headache.

As we are using the "java.ecore" in different places in our multi-module project, I would like to avoid using a relative path and instead place the "java.ecore" in a separate module and reference this module through some dependency defined in the Acceleo plugin (or similar).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use URIs with the platform:/resource and/or platform:/plugin schemes.

Comment: well this sounds promissing.How do I expose my "java.ecore" with an URI of one of these types? - If you can send me a link to a documentation explaining this, I would be happy :-)

Comment: Deploy java.ecore (inside an Eclipse plugin) in your development Eclipse, and use the "platform:/plugin" scheme
Or if the acceleo you are developing is meant to be deployed as plug-ins, then you can add a plug-in alongside your acceleo that deploys the java.ecore then you can use the "platform:/resource".

But re-reading your question, why are you using a java.ecore, when you can use EDataTypes to refer to Java types such as java.io.Closeable?

Comment: thanks for the further reply, but I have some troubles here:

Comment: 1. the "java.ecore" that I have referenced with a relative path in "project.ecore" is displayed in the Eclipse Editor with "platform:/resource/java.ecore". So I do not know how this might help?

2. Acctually we are not using Eclipse and the graphical editor but only IntelliJ and Acceleo

3. I can create an eClassifier and put the Supertype EDataType, but how can I refer to java.io.Closeable with this?

Again I like to read documentation to help myself, but I do not find answers to my questions in any of these oO

Comment: You probably want to procure the "EMF: Eclipse Modeling Framework, 2nd Edition" book which is the reference documentation.
You want to create an EDataType whose "class instance name" (can't remember the exact denomination) is the string "java.util.Closeable". This will work just like Ecore's EString EDataType maps to java's String (you can look it up in ecore.ecore).